# ANTLR grammar for C pre-processor

Tags: antlr, c-preprocessor

I download a c preprocessor grammar on the antlr website.But it has an error and I have no idea about how to correct it.

```
     macroExpansion  
: id=IDENTIFIER WS? LPAREN WS?   RPAREN -> ^(EXPAND $id)
| id=IDENTIFIER WS? LPAREN WS? macArgs  WS? RPAREN -> ^(EXPAND $id macArgs?)
```

rule macroExpansion will go wrong for the code below:

```
      typedef VOID (WINAPI *PFIBER_START_ROUTINE)( LPVOID lpFiberParameter );
```

Because tokens following VOID would be considered as arguments,but in fact VOID is just a macro not a function marco.

How can I change the grammar?Hope anyone can help me.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since the rule must start with `IDENTIFIER` followed by a `LPAREN`, I can't see it ever match input like `typedef VOID (` since the `typedef` isn't accounted for.

By only looking at the `macroExpansion`:

```
macroExpansion  
 : id=IDENTIFIER WS? LPAREN WS?   RPAREN -> ^(EXPAND $id)
 | id=IDENTIFIER WS? LPAREN WS? macArgs  WS? RPAREN -> ^(EXPAND $id macArgs?)
 ;                            //   ^                                   ^
                              //   |                                   |
                              //  not optional                        optional
```

I'd be a bit skeptical about the rest of the grammar though: the `macArgs?` is made optional in the rewrite rule, but that is not correct: the left hand side isn't optional. It could be rewritten like this:

```
macroExpansion  
 : id=IDENTIFIER WS? LPAREN WS? (macArgs WS?)? RPAREN -> ^(EXPAND $id macArgs?)
 ;
```

in which case `macArgs?` *is* correct.